# How to get the mac address of connected client in postgresql log?

Tags: database, postgresql, client, connect, mac-address

Whenever user connects to PostgreSQL database, i want to show the MAC address of that connected user in the log file of PostgreSQL. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#guc-log-line-prefix

> ```
> %a    Application name    yes
> %u    User name   yes
> %d    Database name   yes
> %r    Remote host name or IP address, and remote port yes
> %h    Remote host name or IP address  yes
> %p    Process ID  no
> %t    Time stamp without milliseconds no
> %m    Time stamp with milliseconds    no
> %n    Time stamp with milliseconds (as a Unix epoch)  no
> %i    Command tag: type of session's current command  yes
> %e    SQLSTATE error code no
> %c    Session ID: see below   no
> %l    Number of the log line for each session or process, starting at 1   no
> %s    Process start time stamp    no
> %v    Virtual transaction ID (backendID/localXID) no
> %x    Transaction ID (0 if none is assigned)  no
> %q    Produces no output, but tells non-session processes to stop at this point in the string; ignored by session processes   no
> %%    Literal %
> ```

you can't.

Of course you can get it form arp cache or other system utility, but not with postgres `log_line_prefix`